# IE Incompability for header title

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Working on the following site:

[Markup Medya](http://www.markupmedya.com/)

If you look at the header, there is header text which displays fine on Firefox and chrome, but in IE 10 it shows very small. Not sure what s wrong there and need help with that.

Comment: Where are you importing the `Lobster Two` font, all you have is `font-family: 'Lobster Two',cursive;` but no reference to those font files..

Comment: I think the problem is also IE doesnt know woff file. However, it does work fine Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Please always specify the IE version(s) you're testing with when asking IE-related questions. There are large differences between IE versions, and it is very often a relevant factor.

Comment: Right, therefore you have different font families. The font sizes are the same.

Comment: I am testing on IE 10. Added to the question.

Comment: @DarthVader - also, don't use `<` for visual purposes, instead use the character entity, `&lt;` and `&gt;` - otherwise IE might render it as a broken tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a font issue. You have several `@font-face` declarations in your CSS, but you are only specifying font files in the the `.woff` format.

This will give you an issue in more than just IE.

Please note that in order to support *all* browsers, you will need to supply your fonts in several formats -- to cover all the browsers in common use you'll need `.eof`, `.woff`, and `.ttf` formats.

See this [Bulletproof @font-face](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) article for more detailed discussion of which browsers support which formats and how to write your `@font-face` declarations in order to get the best possible cross-browser coverage.

If you haven't got your fonts in all the required formats, you can use a tool like [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to help you.